# Skip arg parameter in createAsyncThunk

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

I want to skip the first parameter `arg` of the createAsynchThunk, to access only to the `extra` parameter to acess the api service I'm sending as extra parameter, is there a way I can skip the `arg` parameter without using `_`, `undefined` or anything like that?

```
createAsyncThunk(
    'module/fetchModule',
    async (undefined, { extra: api }) => {
        const { data } = await api.get('myendpoint');
        const normalized = normalize(data, [myEntity]);
        return normalized.entities;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you would need to give it a name. The args are optional for thunks so you don't need to provide anything when calling it.